# React svg image not rendering with use tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg

I have a simple component here which takes in any svg image and stroke color and renders the styled svg accordingly. There are no error messages, just not rendering. I tried replacing the SVG and use tag with a simple image, and it renders the component fine - meaning that the SVG and use tag are the issues here. Not sure why. Any suggestions?

```
import React from 'react
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Truck from './Truck.svg'

const SVG = styled.svg`
  stroke: ${props => props.stroke || '#66CC00'};
`;

const Icon = props => {    
  const { src } = props;
  return (
    <SVG xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" {...props}>
      <use xlinkHref={src} />
    </SVG>
  );
};

const RenderIcon = () => <Icon src={Truck} stroke={red} />
```

For reference, this was what I was trying to duplicate: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6cr17y

Comment: The `xlinkHref` attribute is deprecated so probably best not to use it - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `image` SVG element, I could see the svg image.

**Updated code** - updated code to use `use` and `href`. Also updated the sandbox. This should apply the `stroke` property correctly.

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { ReactComponent as Truck } from "./Settings.svg";

const SVG = styled.svg`
  stroke: ${(props) => props.stroke || "#66CC00"};
`;

const Icon = ({ stroke }) => {
  return (
    <SVG viewBox="0 0 512 512" stroke={stroke}>
      <Truck />
      <use href={Truck} />
    </SVG>
  );
};

const RenderIcon = () => <Icon stroke={"red"} />;

export default RenderIcon;
```

Working example here - https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-clarke-73g8g?file=/src/App.js

OR,

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { ReactComponent as Truck } from "./Settings.svg";

const SVG = styled.svg`
  stroke: ${(props) => props.stroke || "#66CC00"};
`;

const Icon = ({ src, stroke }) => {
  return (
    <SVG viewBox="0 0 512 512" stroke={stroke}>
      {src()}
      <use href={src} />
    </SVG>
  );
};

const RenderIcon = () => <Icon src={Truck} stroke={"red"} />;

export default RenderIcon;
```

Comment: I don't think this method lets the svg color to change. Do you have a version where the stroke style gets applied to the image?

Comment: Updated code that should apply the stroke correctly

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Create React App you can do this:

```
import React from "react";
import { ReactComponent as Truck } from "./truck.svg";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MySvgComponent stroke="blue" svgToRender={() => <Truck />} />
    </div>
  );
}

function MySvgComponent({ strokeColor = "red", svgToRender }) {
  return (
    <>
      {svgToRender()}
      <svg>
        <use href="#mytruck" fill="green" stroke={strokeColor} />
      </svg>
    </>
  );
}
```

If not, you would need to install [SVGR](https://react-svgr.com/docs/webpack/) and use it as a webpack loader.

[image: Edit funny-jang-lo3ip]

Comment: Would there be a solution without using the { ReactComponent as Truck } importing? I preferably want the consumer to just pass in any svg src they want to

Comment: You could use a render prop to pass that around. You still need to import it somewhere though.